# How to arrange 6 people but two are joined and two are seperated

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

We have 6 people lined up.  2 are best friends say A and B and are always next to each other and we have 2 other dudes C and D who are always separated.  Independently I know that there are 240 ways you can pair A and B together and 480 ways you can keep C and D separated but I don't know how to put this together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: 
Consider A and B as 1 person and find the number of ways of arranging 5 people. Now multiply that by 2 as A and B can themselves exchange positions.

Now, consider A and B as a single person and C and D as a single person too and find the ways of arranging 4 people. Multiply that by 4 as A, B, C and D can internally change positions.

Subtract the second case from first to reach your answer.

Comment: So 240 - 96? That makes a lot of sense now that you said it. can't believe it was so simple

Comment: @imarben007 That's correct!. You can accept the answer if you got it.

Comment: Appreciate it. Many thanks!